# Remove/handle experimental type pd.NA pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am unsure how to remove/handle pd.NA experimental data type, it is causing me problems, for example in the code snipped below, with pd.NA it functions differently:

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

print (pd.__version__)
print ("with pd.nan --> working")
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3,4,np.nan], 'b': [2,3,4,5,np.nan], 'c': [10, 1,2,3,np.nan]})
Conditions_group = [
    (df.values == 1) | (df.values == 2),
    (df.values == 3) | (df.values == 4)
]
choices = ["1&2", "3&4"]
print(Conditions_group)
new_df  = np.select(Conditions_group, choices, default=np.nan)
print(new_df)


print ("with pd.NA -> not workign  ")
df.replace(np.nan, pd.NA, inplace=True)
Conditions_group = [
    (df.values == 1) | (df.values == 2),
    (df.values == 3) | (df.values == 4)
]
print(Conditions_group)
new_df  = np.select(Conditions_group, choices, default=np.nan)
print(new_df)

----- OUT ----
1.4.4
with pd.nan --> working
[array([[ True,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]]), array([[False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False]])]
[['1&2' '1&2' 'nan']
 ['1&2' '3&4' '1&2']
 ['3&4' '3&4' '1&2']
 ['3&4' 'nan' '3&4']
 ['nan' 'nan' 'nan']]
with pd.NA -> not workign  
[False, False]
nan
```

I am unable to find where, but it seems to me that either when exporting/importing/doing something to the data, the pd.NA reappear in it. Since it is experimental, I think it best to always remove the pd.NA.

- Is there a way to stop pandas from ever using pd.NA?
- Should I write a funciton that every time i re-import the data checks for pd.NA and remvoes them?

It also seems to fail with simple operations like replace, for exmaple when type of a is category:

```py
df['a'] = df['a'].astype("category")
print (df.replace(pd.NA, np.nan))

--OUT--
TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous
```